# Running mac os x c++ program working with OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I am running Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29). I am working on a macbook pro.

I have installed brew and the following packages:

```
brew install glfw3
brew install glew
brew install glm
```

Here is my c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // Should be true for macOS, according to GLFW docs, to get core profile.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    // According to Apple docs, non-core profiles are limited to version 2.1.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test 1", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // glGetString(GL_VERSION) is NULL at this point

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the command line i am running to compile my program:

```
g++ program.cpp -I/opt/X11/include -L/opt/X11/lib -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW
```

There is a runtime problem because i get a NULL window.
I have compiled the same code on a Linux virtual machine and it works great...

Comment: Have you added "OpenGL.framework" to your build setup?

Comment: I do not work with a cocoa application or Xcode. The file i put in my question is a text file

Comment: Try replacing (or adding, I'm not sure) `-lGL` with `-framework OpenGL` and be sure you have this framework dir on path.(likely `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework`)

Comment: Try using `glfwSetErrorCallback` to print the error that GLFW gives you. When `glfwCreateWindow` returns `NULL` it means that window creation has failed and is an internal problem, possibly with your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the GLFW docs: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
// Should be true for macOS, according to GLFW docs, to get core profile.
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
// According to Apple docs, non-core profiles are limited to version 2.1.
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Also see: https://developer.apple.com/opengl/OpenGL-Capabilities-Tables.pdf

Comment: I think you should swap the comments, asking for a *core profile* uses `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`

Comment: Strange: glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns NULL

Comment: @Ripi2: The comments look right to me. Non-core profiles *are* limited to 2.1, so you want a core profile.

Comment: @Bob5421: It seems like you are not reading the GLFW documentation. Go to http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html "Before you can use the OpenGL API, you must have a current OpenGL context."

Comment: I did not put all my code, but in fact i have glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); (see edit)

Comment: Try `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>` instead of `<GL/gl.h>` and don't use GLEW.

Comment: This answer does not do anything. My console still prints out "OpenGL 2.1 INTEL-14.2.16". I linked my binary with the OpenGL library, put those lines. No change whatsoever.

Comment: @Matt: What GPU do you have? Go to Apple menu > About This Mac, and read the description of the computer (e.g. “MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)” and what it says for graphics (e.g. “Intel Iris 1536 MB”).