# How to "upgrade" to OpenGL 3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I've been reading a lot about this but haven't been able to resolve anything yet. I am trying to draw a colored triangle with OpenGL3 but I get the following error:

*terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'   what():  Compilation error for vertex shader (from file ./TP1/shaders/triangle.vs.glsl): 0:1(10): **error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported.** Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES*

When I run **glxinfo | grep -i opengl** I get:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 6000 (Broadwell GT3)  
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8 
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) 
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 
OpenGL context flags: (none) 
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile 
OpenGL extensions: 
OpenGL ES profile version string: 
OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.0.8 
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string:
OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10 
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I tried **export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3** which enables me to execute the code but I just get a weird triangle, not a nice equilateral multicolored one.
Here's my full code:

```
#include <glimac/SDLWindowManager.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glimac/Program.hpp>
#include <glimac/FilePath.hpp>

using namespace glimac;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize SDL and open a window
    SDLWindowManager windowManager(800, 600, "GLImac");

    // Initialize glew for OpenGL3+ support
    GLenum glewInitError = glewInit();
    if(GLEW_OK != glewInitError) {
        std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(glewInitError) << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "OpenGL Version : " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLEW Version : " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;

    //load shaders and tell OpenGL to use them
    FilePath applicationPath(argv[0]);
    Program program = loadProgram(applicationPath.dirPath() + "shaders/triangle.vs.glsl",
                                    applicationPath.dirPath() + "shaders/triangle.fs.glsl");
    program.use();

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); 

    //triangle data
    GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, //2 coordinates + 1 0 0 color
                         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
                         0.0f, 0.5f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (15*(sizeof(float))), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao); 
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    const GLuint VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION = 3;
    const GLuint VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR = 8;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR);

    const GLvoid* bouche;
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (0*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)), bouche);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (2*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)), bouche);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (2*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);


    // Application loop:
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
        // Event loop:
        SDL_Event e;
        while(windowManager.pollEvent(e)) {
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                done = true; // Leave the loop after this iteration
            }
        }

        //clean window
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Update the display
        windowManager.swapBuffers();
    }

    //liberate allocated memory on GPU (the vbo and vao)
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use glew, then enable additional extensions by `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. See the [GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) which says:

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

```cpp
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum glewInitError = glewInit();
if(GLEW_OK != glewInitError) {
    std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(glewInitError) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

When an named buffer object is bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then the last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is treated as a byte offset into that buffer.
When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called, then the vertex array specification is stored in the state vector of the currently bound vertex array object. The buffer which is currently bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the attribute and the name (value) of the object is stored in the state vector of the VAO.
Further note, that the 5th parameter (*stride*) of `glVertexAttribPointer`, specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attribute.

This means before the call of `glVertexAttribPointer` the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) and the [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) have to be bound.
The *stride* parameter has to be `5*sizeof(Glfloat)`, because the vertex attributes consist of the 5  `GLfloat` values (x, y, r, g, b).
The offset for `VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION` is 0 and for `VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR` it is `2*sizeof(GLfloat)`, because (r, g b) is after (x, y). Note, that `GL_FLOAT` is an enumerator constant and not data type, so `2*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

```cpp
//triangle data
GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, //2 coordinates + 1 0 0 color
                        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
                        0.0f, 0.5f,  0.f, 0.f, 1.f };

// create vertex buffer object
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// vertex array object
 GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao); 
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// specify the array of generic vertex attribute data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); // if "vbo" is still bound then that would not be necessary
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR,    3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), 2*sizeof(GLfloat));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR);

// the following is not necessary, you can let them bound
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Make sure that the vertex attribute indices are correct:

```cpp
const GLuint VERTEX_ATTR_POSITION = 3;
const GLuint VERTEX_ATTR_COLOR = 8;
```

3 and 8 are possible but seem strange. Not this should be the resource indices of the attributes which may be set by [Layout qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) or can be get by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) after the program is linked.

---

By the way the coordinates for an equilateral triangle are for example:

```cpp
GLfloat vertices[] = { 
     x        y      r    g    b
    -0.866f, -0.5f,  1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
     0.866f, -0.5f,  0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
     0.0f,    1.0f,  0.f, 0.f, 1.f };
```

Comment: @Monica Why do you get an error? I thought you get *"a weird triangle, not a nice equilateral multicolored one"*. Possibly the answer to [Running mac os x c++ program working with OpenGL 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551933/running-mac-os-x-c-program-working-with-opengl-3-3) can help.

Comment: I get the same error as stated above at the beginning of my paragraph: error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported.
If I do the export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 command again, with your modifications of the code, I don't get any triangle.

Comment: @Monica `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` is missing. I've extended the answer, see the first paragraph.