# OpenGL 1.2+ on a system that supports OpenGL 4.1 [NOT a duplicate]

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

I'm working with GLFW in Xcode 11.3.

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running macOS 10.15 Catalina won't support any shader `#version` above `120`, and I would really like to use a newer version.

How do I tell my system to use a newer version of OpenGL instead of 1.2?

---

People keep referring to this site: https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context

However, the below code doesn't change anything for me.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

I originally looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552181/3763235), again with the same code as above. Since it didn't work for me, I decided to ask a new question on how to fix this. This is not a "duplicate", as this is a new problem where the original solution doesn't work.

---

Looking at [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) I found that my particular MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) has an Intel HD Graphics 4000 which supports OpenGL 4.1 and OpenCL 1.2. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) I found that OpenGL 4.1 supports `#version 410`.

So implementing that information:

```cpp
bool Window::init()
{
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_Width, m_Height, m_Title, NULL, NULL);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    if (!m_Window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_Window);
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_Window, this);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, window_resize);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(m_Window, key_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(m_Window, mouse_button_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(m_Window, cursor_position_callback);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "OpenGL " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

```
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * position;
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
OpenGL 2.1 INTEL-14.2.16
Failed to compile vertex shader!
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '410' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
```

Clearly, 2.1 is less than 4.1 (and 3.2, which I also tried before looking up the aforementioned two articles); so no, the code everyone keeps tossing around does not work for me. Hence why this is not a duplicate of [Running mac os x c++ program working with OpenGL 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552181/3763235).

Comment: Also: https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context

Comment: @KenThomases can you please take off the [duplicate] from my question? I've added more elaboration in the post as to why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: ...why are you calling [`glfwWindowHint()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga7d9c8c62384b1e2821c4dc48952d2033) *after* you've created a window?  The hints only affect the next `glfwCreateWindow()` call, not a previous one.

Comment: @genpfault Lol. Didn't even see that that one line was a bove, not below. Now I'm at least running the right version of OpenGL xD – I still don't see any shaders in my window though. Perhaps I should ask a new question regarding the shaders more specifically.

Comment: @genpfault How come the above pasted `glfwWindowHint`s make me unable to draw anything onto my screen? Taking those hints away enables me to use immediate mode `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); … glEnd();` however not when I add the hints before creating my Window. Help?

Comment: @Matt: Core contexts (as requested by `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`) remove access to all the old fixed-function stuff like `glBegin()`.  You have to move fully to the programmable pipeline.  Don't forget a VAO!

Comment: @genfault After some fiddling I found out where I forgot some lines for my VAO as well. My shaders are working now. Thanks a lot for your input! :D